# Manipulate two cols from csv file

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, csv

First of all, let me tell that I spent almost 1 hour testing a lot of possible related questions from SO but no success. It is complicated to me (beginner user). If I had typed number by number I would had finished earlier. But the idea is to learn, always. So I would like to understand.

Consider the following example:

```
>>> np.random.rand(3,2)
array([[ 0.14022471,  0.96360618],
       [ 0.37601032,  0.25528411],
       [ 0.49313049,  0.94909878]])
```

This is the kind of object I need to use with some Voronoi codes. But my data comes from a csv file.

I have a csv file with header and I need the columns `clat` and `clong`. I would like to obtain the output like this:

```
array([[ clat_1,  clong_1],
       [ clat_2,  clong_2],
                ...
       [ clat_N,  clong_N]])
```

so that with `print` the output would be like this:

```
[[ 0.19151945  0.62210877]
 [ 0.43772774  0.78535858]
 [ 0.77997581  0.27259261]
 [ 0.39720258  0.78873014]
 [ 0.31683612  0.56809865]]
```

I loaded the csv file with

```
csv_file='./demog.csv'
demog = np.genfromtxt(csv_file, delimiter=',', skip_header=0, skip_footer=0, names=True,dtype=None)
```

After I tried `clat=demog['clat']` and `clong=demog['clong']` but `print clat` does not look to be a single column.

How to create such `N x 2` object (I even don't know its name: array, list, matrix, table,...)

Answer (score 1):

clat will give you the entire lat column, and clong will give you the entire long column.  To put them together in an array like you mentioned with [lat, long] pairs you can use zip:

```
array = []

for lat, long in zip(clat, clong):
    array.append([lat, long])

array = np.array(array)
print array
```

Comment: Numbers (for example `-16.203697`) from csv was extended (to `-16.203696999999998`). How to keep same precision? Also, the print output is not like I posted above (maybe because the digits number?).

Comment: Also, my Voronoi code returned `plt.plot(points[:,0], points[:,1], 'ko')
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple`. `points` is `array`.

Comment: I used your code together with `points=np.array(points)` to have the desired output. If you edit I could accept it. Thanks.

Comment: `array.append(list([lat, long]))` and `array=np.array(array)`

Comment: I see what you're saying .  The np.array gets you a new lat/long pair on each line for printing.  Cool.  Edited the answer above.